# Short story about a boxer/fighter who can teleport a few millimeters, which gives him an advantage in the ring

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, teleportation

The story is about a boxer/fighter who can teleport a few millimeters, which gives him an advantage in the ring.

I believe in the end of the story he uses his teleportation powers to save someone from a car accident? I read it 15-20 years ago, so the story must be older than that.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

This is ***Ernie*** by Timothy Zahn, published in [Time Bomb and Zahndry Others](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/216439.Time_Bomb_and_Zahndry_Others).

A boxer uses a short-distance teleportation power to become a Golden Gloves champion and saves a woman from a car accident.

> “Coach, have you ever heard of teleportation?” When I shook my head,
> he went on, “You read about it sometimes in those science fiction
> books. It’s when you go from one place to another, like, in no time at
> all.”
>
> “All kinds of crazy stuff in those books. So?”
>
> “Well, that’s what I do. I can ‘port about an inch at a time, and I do
> it when I’m hitting or ducking a punch. It’s just enough distance to
> throw off the other guy’s timing, usually.”
>
> I just sat there, wondering if he was putting me on. He must have seen
> that in my face somehow, because his eyes started looking wary again.
> “You don’t believe me,” he muttered.
>
> “How about giving me a demonstration?” I suggested. “How fast did you
> say you could… teleport?”
>
> “I can move an inch at a time, but I can do it five or six times a
> second if I need to.”